# How many times does Laravel 5.7 execute the SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

Learning Laravel 5.7 on Laracasts.com, it shown how to get `1:N` relationship records from the database with Eloquent model objects as following.

```
// One SQL query is being executed here.
$project = Project::first();

// Another SQL query must be executed here to be abled to count the tasks. Right?
if ($project->tasks->count()) {

    // Is another SQL query being executed here to fetch the task's  records related to the project? 
    foreach ($project->tasks as $task) {

         echo $task->name;
    }
}
```

How many SQL query has been executed with the above approach? I am not sure 2 or 3 SQL queries are being executed.

Comment: There are two queries being run here. The first query to load the project, then the second to load `$project->tasks` into a collection. Then both `count()` and the foreach are run on the loaded collection, but does not require more database queries.

Comment: Thus, due to $project->tasks right before ->count() executes the SELECT * FROM ... query and count them right after when count() is being called, instead of executing the SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... query.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [DB::enableQueryLog](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging)/`DB::getQueryLog`:

> Laravel can optionally log in memory all queries that have been run
>   for the current request. Be aware that in some cases, such as when
>   inserting a large number of rows, this can cause the application to
>   use excess memory. To enable the log, you may use the enableQueryLog
>   `method: DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();`

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();

// One SQL query is being executed here.
$project = Project::first();

// Another SQL query must be executed here to be abled to count the tasks. Right?
if ($project->tasks->count()) {

    // Is another SQL query being executed here to fetch the task's  records related to the project?
    foreach ($project->tasks as $task) {

        echo $task->name;
    }
}

# queries so far
\DB::getQueryLog();
```

- [Listening For Query Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#listening-for-query-events)
- [Query Logging](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging)

Comment: It does not answer the question, but gives me a new knowledge to get the answer, thus indirect answer. I voted 1 for you as useful answer!